# Hamburger animation with @keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, hamburger-menu

I am working on a hamburger animation. I have done the animation with a simple css animation with a class, that I toggle in the js. The only problem with  that of course is that the animation plays only when I toggle the class, and when I close it the div doesn't contain the class with the animation. I understand the problem, and I have done research but I couldn't find any that works with animation. Is it even possible to make it work with that?

Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const Close = () =>{

    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const line1 = document.querySelector('.line1');
    const line2 = document.querySelector('.line2');
    const line3 = document.querySelector('.line3');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        line1.classList.toggle('line1-active');
        line2.classList.toggle('line2-active');
        line3.classList.toggle('line3-active');
    });
}

Close();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: black;
}

.burger{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.burger div{
    background-color: white;
    height: 5px;
    width: 45px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.line1-active{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    animation: top 0.3s ease-in both;
}

.line2-active{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

.line3-active{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    animation: bottom 0.3s ease-in both;
}

@keyframes top{
    0%{
        top: 0px;
    }

    33%{
        top: 10px;
    }

    66%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}

@keyframes bottom{
    0%{
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    33%{
        bottom: 10px;
    }

    66%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100%{
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Burger animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see these [examples](https://codepen.io/NikalLawde/pen/poPRgVe). I made these a month back.

Comment: Check this answer [How to achieve reverse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68523178/15545116) and this [Reverse Multiple CSS Keyframe Animations On Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68627424/15545116)